# VSCode/DataWeave Extension launch.json

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm playing to the VSCode with DataWeave extension, and trying to create an element in the "configurations" array inside the "launch.json" file in order to kick off a debug session based on my own configuration preference, and wondering if anyone can share some information.

It seems that there are two different possible values for "type" in the "launch.json": the "data-weave" type and the "data-weave-testing" type.

These two types of elements in the "configurations" array look like this (not considering requesting "attach" for the "remote debugging" case):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "data-weave-testing",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DataWeave Run Mapping",
            "mainFile": "",
            "testToRun": "",
            "port": 6565
        },
        {
            "type": "data-weave",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DataWeave Run Mapping",
            "mainFile": "",
            "scenario": "",
            "port": 6565
        }
    ]
}
```

How can we specify these elements: "scenario", "testToRun", and "mainFile" in both types? I was trying to use the relative path but no luck so far.

One scenario I tried is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "data-weave",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DataWeave Run Mapping",
            "mainFile": "src/main/dw/mainFunctions_Mapping.dwl",
            "scenario": "src/main/test/resources/mainFunctions_Mapping/Playground/inputs/payload.json",
            "port": 6565
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried use various values for the scenario field, but it just kept complaining that "Unable to resolve reference of: 'payload'"

Any help will be greatly appreciated!